# Copy dynamic cells from one sheet to another starting from the top

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I am creating an input box to search for data in column A.

If for example the data is found in column A row 243, I want to copy that cell(a range in my case) to another spreadsheet starting Column A row 2.

Could anyone help me with this issue? Would be much appreciated.

Thank you

```
Sub Sales_Rep()


Dim r As Integer
Dim c As Integer

Dim X As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Range


' Deteling the extra sheets of previous Sales representatives

If Worksheets.Count > 4 Then

Worksheets("Sales Rep").Delete

End If

X = Application.InputBox("Please insert the Sales Rep Code")


' Calculating the number of rows and Columns

Worksheets("Data Set Macro").Activate

r = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
c = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

Debug.Print r
Debug.Print c

' Add another tab where we can see all the details of the selected sales representative

Worksheets.Add.Name = "Sales Rep"

' Copy of the header from the original tab to the new tab

Worksheets("Data Set Macro").Range("A1:D1").Copy _
    Worksheets("Sales Rep").Range("A1:D1")


'Worksheets("Data Set Macro").Activate


 For i = 2 To r
 'For j = 2 To 5


   Worksheets("Data Set Macro").Activate

    If Cells(i, 1) = X Then

            Worksheets("Data Set Macro").Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, c)).Select
                 Selection.Copy

        Worksheets("Sales Rep").Activate
            Worksheets("Sales Rep").Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, c)).Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste


    End If

'Next j
Next i




End Sub
```

Comment: Edit your question and make the problem clear. You are creating an input box that search for what and on what rows or lines?

Comment: I am creating an input box to search for data in column A. 

If for example the data is found in column A row 243, I want to copy that cell(a range in my case) to another spreadsheet starting Column A row 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim ol, nw As Worksheet

Set ol = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Old")
Set nw = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("New")


    ncell = ol.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

With ol.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(ncell, 1))
 Set dist = .Find(X, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not dist Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = dist.Address
        Do
            ncellnw = nw.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
            nw.Cells(ncellnw,1).Value = firstAddress
            Set dist = .FindNext(dist)
        Loop While Not dist Is Nothing And dist.Address <> firstAddress
    End If
End With
```

It should work, where you declare Worksheets, then Search for the value in X (String on inputbox).

Where ncell and ncellnw gives the last row with something written on column A